# Theorem on flat ruled surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request

I cannot find the proof of a well-known theorem on ruled surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The theorem is:

> A ruled Surface which is flat is one of the following:
>
> - A Cone
> - A Cylinder
> - A Tangent developable

Can someone provide a proof of this result or at least a reference?

Comment: You can find useful http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/CurveSuperfici/AG14.pdf

Comment: The statement is true only locally (or globally if you assume real analyticity). See Exercise 12 on p. 42 and Exercise 10 on p. 65 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).